# Covering AC coolant pipes in finished room

Tags: pipe, soffit

We had a heat pump installed, and the only path from the coils to the outdoor unit went through our finished basement room. Unfortunately, the pipes were run about 18 inches down from the ceiling, so they are a real eye sore. (They were supposed to be run near the ceiling, but HVAC ducts got in the way)

I want to cover them up in a clean way, with as little intrusion into the room as possible. Damping the noise from them when the coolant is running through the pipes would be a bonus, since this is our tv watching room.

If I try to build a soffit, i think it will have to be quite large since the first joist is fairly far from the wall, and I assume I’d have to attach to that. Are there any other common ways of covering something like this that isn't hack-y and won’t need to be redone if/when we re-sell the house down the road?

Thank you!

[image: Pipe running across front wall near ceiling]
[image: Detail of pipe along wall, exiting room]

Comment: valance ... wood or cloth or ......

Comment: what are the dimensions ?

Comment: [Line hide](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Line-Set-Covers-17880000) is the standard solution, but is still not exactly pretty, and may or may not be large enough to cover the piping - particularly where it needs to step out to pass through the wall. Retrofitting it is also not ideal.

Comment: Create a [GNDN Conduit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Treknobabble/comments/1w8lom/gndn_tubes_on_the_enterprise/).

Comment: _Clicks link, gives @HABO a vote for the laughs_

Comment: You can put blocking between joists to get your soffit positioned exactly where you want it.

Comment: [Best tool and blade to cut 8" pvc](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/77539/best-tool-and-blade-to-cut-8-pvc)

Comment: GNDN is perfect, I'm going to install some in my workspace as a side project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build a chase.  Extend it from the wall enough to be used as a shelf, and thick enough to cover the refrigerant lines.  Basically like a floating shelf.  Make it removable in case the lines need to be accessed.  Put knicknacks on the shelf (or hang your speakers from it and reclaim the floor space).

You could even stuff the chase/shelf with sound deadening insulation to reduce the refrigerant gurgle.

Comment: This is a great idea, thank you. It's a more useful, less intrusive version of the soffit I was thinking about.

Comment: Thinking a bit more, it would be easy to support the shelf/chase: if you basically make a squared off U section, you can fasten some boards to the side walls.  These boards would be the right size to slot into the U shape, and you would be able to just slide the shelf right on.  If you need to support heavy things you'd want to build some internal support in the space in front of the refrigerant lines.  If you can slide a small piece of 1x behind the lines you might be able to use that as a way to support the middle of the shelf.

Answer (score 1):

A big hunk of cove molding, (or some other shape that appeals, and does the job) all around the room. Put strip lights on it facing up for some indirect lighting, and stuff the part with the pipe full of rockwool.

If you just do the wall with the pipe, it's *odd.* If you do it all around the room, it's **a feature.** If you add the lighting, it's **more** of a feature.

Comment: May do the indirect lighting, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My biggest concern would be how to handle the potential condensation.

Right now it would merely drip on your floor and evaporate.

If you hide it with crown molding or something then you could create a pool of water against your wall.

Whatever solution you decide, make sure to add a few weep holes so that any problem with the line-set reveals itself.

If you'd rather have a flat wall with nothing glaring at you then you could consider erecting a new wall in front of the line-set.

Answer (score 0):

Put a bookshelf there with a false back.  The false back hides the line set.

Have hinged-down lids on the bookshelf if that would improve the aesthetic.   Now the TV appears to be inset into the wall.

Comment: Actually, this is a pretty good idea, maybe a combo of this plus the chase. Thanks!